# Is there anything special to know before using powdered vanilla?

Tags: baking, food-safety, flavor

Is there anything special to know before using powdered vanilla?  I use the liquid vanilla extract quite a bit in making a lot of things, especially chocolate and key lime puddings but am looking for alcohol free and organic form. It sounds like the powdered form provides a stronger flavor which sounds good to me.
Thank you for being there.  This is a tremendous offering for people who want to create great foods...